# Can I ground my portable generator into the third prong of an active outside receptacle?

Tags: generator

I have read that it is best/safest to use the house ground to ground my generator. Why will using the ground connection in my outside active receptacle work, or not work, when grounding my 4000 watt inverter generator with 2, 20 amp outlets?

Comment: I don't understand. How are you getting power to your appliances?

Comment: What are you powering with this generator and how?

Comment: Generators are a separately derived system. They are internally grounded. Unless you expect a lightning strike on your portable generator the house ground won’t do much other than violate several code articles if connecting this way.